# Using Primefaces 5.1 How to change the Button Icon style at runtime only using javascript. (no ajax call)

Tags: javascript, primefaces, styles, icons

I 'm using PrimeFaces 5.1. Without any server request I will change the icon of one button. The Button Icon which have to be used should be defined (or changed) by a javascript method.

Idea:
Pressing a second Button I using a JavaScript Method oncomplete to define the icon which have to be used. And advice the first button to update itself with this new icon.

Problem: I don't know how to set the icon Parameter of the `p:commandButton` using a JavaScript Method. I have to use a Bean: `p:comandButton icon="#{myBean.getIcon}" ....` Nor I can define the style or icon the button have to use directly by accessing the javascript primefaces object of the button.

Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

The icon on the button is set via css. If you look in the generated html you can see that. (ui-icon-disk below in the first span)

```
<button id="j_idt87:withIcon" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left" type="submit" style="margin-right:20px;" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt87:withIcon',u:'j_idt87:growl'});return false;" name="j_idt87:withIcon" role="button" aria-disabled="false">    
    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-disk"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">With Icon</span>
</button>
```

By manipulating the class with e.g. jquery, you can change the icon easily (hoping to not get downvoted since I do not post a complete solution but leave some work to the poster)